# JS settimeout doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I've looked at similar questions but can't get `setTimeout` to work with a `forEach` loop, even using the index to increase the delay:

```
pointArray.forEach(function(p) {
    setTimeout(addPt(p, 24, red), pointArray.indexOf(p) * 100000);

});
```

See that I've increased the delay to a measurable amount of ms and have multiplied by the increasing index - I know the index works as I console log out and it increases up to 100 as that is the array length.

Regardless the `console.log` I have in `addPt` happens all at the same time. What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you simply need to pass a reference and not the result of a function call.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){addPt(p, 24, red);}, pointArray.indexOf(p)*100000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addPt(p, 24, red)
```

You are invoking the method immediately, instead of giving setTimeout a method reference.  Such as

```
setTimeout(addPt, 3000);
```

However since you are providing inputs, there are a couple ways to do this with a method reference.

```
//a
setTimeout(function(){ addPt(p, 24, red); }, 3000);
//b
setTimeout(addPt.bind(addPt, p, 24, red), 3000);
//c as noted by Jonas W
setTimeout(addPt, 3000, p, 24, red);
```

Both will pass a method reference to setTimeout and let -it- execute the function after the duration passes.